# Python: eval() combined with list comprehension does not work in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I executed the following code in my MacBook Pro, with Python 3.9.8, and the code yielded what I expected.

```
lista = [{'hello': 'foo'}, {'hello': 'bar'}]
listb = ["a['hello']"]
for a in lista:
    print([eval(x) for x in listb])

# result
['foo']
['bar']
```

However, if I execute the exactly same code on AWS Lambda, an error occurrs:

> ```
> [ERROR] NameError: name 'a' is not defined
> ```

The same error occurs if I replace the list comprehension with map() and a lambda function.
If I use a for loop instead, it works well.

```
lista = [{'hello': 'foo'}, {'hello': 'bar'}]
listb = ["a['hello']"]
for a in lista:
    listc = []
    for x in listb:
        listc.append(eval(x))
    print(listc)

# result
['foo']
['bar']
```

What would be the reason for this?

Comment: Just a guess: It might have something to do with eval() being very prone to security issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is partially based on a guess, so it may be wrong, but here goes:

Guess: The code in AWS Lambda gets wrapped in a function. This is at least plausible, because I get the same error if I wrap it in a function and run it locally.

Now, the [documentation for eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) says

> Note, eval() does not have access to the nested scopes (non-locals) in the enclosing environment.

So, when you run the code at the module level, `a` is a global variable, and the eval:ed expression can see it. However, when the code is wrapped in a function, `a` is function local. Since the list comprehension introduces an even more local scope, the eval:ed expression does not see the function scope! Similarly, a lambda creates an intermediate scope that hides the function scope.

Using for loops, however, does *not* create an intermediate scope, so then eval can see the function scope.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think your answer is correct. I guess I am still not used to considering variable scopes :)